# Replace all spaces except the ones with in HTML tags

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to replace all spaces with html code, i.e. &nbsp, in a string. Currently following, does the replacement but it also replaces the spaces with in html tags like `<a href="http://google.com" />`.

```
string.replaceAll(" ", "&nbsp")
```

But I need it to not change the tags.

Example:

```
String s1 = "Hello!, Check out this <^a href=\"http://www.entrepreneur.com/article/234538\">10 Movies Every Entrepreneur Needs to Watch <^/a>"
```

After replacment, it should be like;

```
String s1 = "Hello!,&nbspCheck&nbspout&nbspthis&nbsp<^a href=\"http://www.entrepreneur.com/article/234538\">10&nbspMovies&nbspEvery&nbspEntrepreneur&nbspNeeds&nbspto&nbspWatch&nbsp<^/a>"
```

Can anybody suggest a more intelligent regex to accomplish the task?

Comment: can you give us more examples of tags that will be used ?

Comment: If only we had variable length lookbehinds...

Comment: @Amir, I added the example.

Comment: @Ammar why are you adding the `^` after the `<` ?

Comment: @Quincunx : my wrong please rollback to the earlier edit or you can edit it further. Thanks

Comment: @Amir, I added cap(^) just to avoid the anchor tag parsing by editor.

Comment: This is a classic case where the technique explained in detail in this question about of [Regex-matching or replacing... except when...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/) can make a very tidy solution. I'll work on a solution for it, give me a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can assume that the only use of `>` and `<` in the string is for the tags, then this regex will work:

```
 (?![^<]*>)
```

[It works for your example.](http://ideone.com/jfaFOD)

How it works:

- matches the space character. This is exactly like what you did.
- `(?!` starts a negative lookahead. This means that this regex will match only if it is not followed by something that matches the regex in the lookahead.
- `[^<]*` matches any character that is not `<`, multiple times
- `>` matches `>`
- `)` closes the lookahead.

In other words, this regex matches any space, but with the requirement there must be a `<` before every `>` after the space.

Answer (score 3):

I know you have already accepted an answer, but your problem has another simple solution that wasn't mentioned. This situation sounds very similar to this question to ["regex-match a pattern, excluding..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)

With all the disclaimers about using regex to parse html, here is a simple way to do it.

We can solve it with a beautifully-simple regex:

```
<[^<>]*>|( )
```

The left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `<tags>`. We will ignore these matches. The right side matches and captures spaces to Group 1, and we know they are the right spaces because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

This full Java program shows how to use the regex (see the results at the bottom of the [online demo](http://ideone.com/WDf66l)):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.List;

class Program {
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception  {

String subject = "Hello!, Check out this <^a href=\"http://www.entrepreneur.com/article/234538\">10 Movies Every Entrepreneur Needs to Watch <^/a>";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<[^<>]*>|( )");
Matcher m = regex.matcher(subject);
StringBuffer b= new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    if(m.group(1) != null) m.appendReplacement(b, "&nbsp;");
    else m.appendReplacement(b, m.group(0));
}
m.appendTail(b);
String replaced = b.toString();
System.out.println(replaced);
} // end main
} // end Program
```

**Reference**

- [How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)
- [How to match a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)